# Change Bootstrap navbar style

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I tried to change the style of a Bootstrap navbar with JavaScript, but I don't know how it works. I can easily change the style with CSS but not with JavaScript.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">HOME</a>
     </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">-</a></li>
           </ul>
     </div>
</nav>
```

I want to change the color, when an `li` is hovered, the color of the brand element and the `border-bottom` of the navbar. What could I do?

Comment: Please post the CSS and the javascript you have said you tried so someone can help you.

Comment: My CSS is already working, but I have not started to write the javascript code, because I have no idea to change the style. I only know how to change single Elements with document.getElementByID  or class name or tagname. But this doesn't work with Bootstra

Comment: That's my CSS:  I dont't know how to formet it correctly in Stack Oveflow.        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #373f43;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
    color: #F33939;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    color: #373f43;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #F33939;
}
.navbar-default{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F33939;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example for you to start with. You should be able to adapt this to you code.

```js
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  }
  );
```

```css
.hover{color:green;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li>Chips</li>
    <li>Socks</li>
  </ul>
```

Cheers

Comment: This code works, but one thing. The font-size is changed, but not the color.

Comment: Yes this is an example of what you can do. You havent given much to go on in your original post. If you look at the CSS that is whats changing based on jquery hover.

Comment: If you want a specific example then let me know and you can build up on that. Also if this is the answer that solves your problem then choose it as the correct answer please.